# smooth in opengl does not work

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, smoothing

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_SRC_COLOR);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);    // Разрешить плавное сглаживание
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);   // Черный фон
glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST); // Сглаживание линий
glEnable(GL_BLEND);         // Разрешить смешивание
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

//set the format and location for verticies
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);

glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals);

glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

//draw the triangles
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numberOfVertices);
```

Here is my code, and now I have no idea why code doesn't work. I'll be very grateful for advice.

Comment: can you add some explanation of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes of course. I read vertexes and normals from file. And this code loads and draws a model. I draw with triangles and the model is perfect, but smooth doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: @Oleg I say the code works perfect, now proof the opposite, by stating what you expect it to do and what it does!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't have proper understanding of the term *smooth* in this context.

First, the `GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT` only affects lines. Furthermore, I refer to [the documentation](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glHint.html).

Second, `glShadeModel()` sets the type of shading your next primitive should have. `GL_SMOOTH` will make the vertices' colors interpolated in each resulting pixel fragment. `GL_FLAT`, however, only take one computed color of a vertex and automatically assign it to each pixel fragment that your primitive represents. Furthermore, I refer to [the documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glShadeModel.xml).

*Your understanding* of smooth is not, like you think, applicable on triangles. If you *really* want a *smooth* model you should increase the number of polygons in the model.